# Store does not have a valid reducer when using redux-toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm having some trouble with redux-toolkit configureStore function, whenever I try to call dispatch on a page it gives me the 'Store does not have a valid reducer' error. I suppose my imports are right and also the store is in the upper level of my index.js file.

This is how it's looking:

store.js file:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import bookReducer from "../reducers/book";

export default configureStore({
  reducer: { books: bookReducer }
});
```

book.js file:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const bookSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'books',
  initialState: {
    bookList: []
  },
  reducers: {
    getBookSuccess: (state, action) => console.log(action.payload),
    getBookFailure: (state, action) => console.log(action.payload),
    setLoading: (state, action) => ({ ...state, loadingTarget: action.loadingTarget, loadingType: action.loadingType })
  }
})

export const { getBookSuccess, getBookFailure, setLoading } = bookSlice.actions;

export default bookSlice.reducer;
```

index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.scss';
import App from './App';
import store from './app/store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import './fontAwesome'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This _looks_ valid.  Can you log what `booksReducer` is in your `store.js` file?  Is it actually a function?

Comment: Oh, your comment made see that not even logging was working, the import was from another store that was in another folder. My mistake! 

Thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it was my mistake, there was two stores (one from the template).
I was importing the original one instead of the one I created.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you change the `configureStore` to this:

```js
export default configureStore({
  reducer: bookReducer
});
```

It should work.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, in the docs, if I pass an object of reducers it calls the combine reducers function. So it was supposed to work...

Comment: @Rodolfo sorry for not helping with resolving your issue & thank you for pointing to a feature of redux-toolkit that I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should change the import name in the store.js file

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import BookReducer from "../reducers/book"; // bookReducer -> BookReducer

export default configureStore({
  reducer: { books: BookReducer } // bookReducer -> BookReducer
});
```